# iOS7 Sprite Kit how to calculate node position when anchor point is changed?

Tags: objective-c, ios7, geometry, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I have a node of **width** by **height** pixels, and I want to put it at **(X,Y)** position that I know.  However, I also need to shift the anchor point (**anchorX**, **anchorY**) of this node arbitrarily.

If I proceed to add the child without accounting for the anchor point, the child node is shifted. I'm trying to compensate for this shift and put the node exactly where I want it to go.

**What equation can I use to account for the anchor point change when adding a node as child?**

So far I'm using something like this, but I'm not sure of the minus signs.

```
 node.center =   CGPointMake(X-width*(0.5-anchorX) ,Y-height*(0.5-anchorY));
```

Comment: The equation I provided appears to work

Answer (score 1):

Instead of trying to come up with a working formula, how about just switching the parent's anchor point back to 0.5, 0.5, adding the child and then going back to the modified anchor point.

OR you can just forgo all the equations and simply set the anchor point of any child object to the same as your parent:

```
SKSpriteNode *object1 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
object1.position = CGPointMake(300, 150);
object1.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(0.1, 0.2);
object1.zRotation = 1;
[self addChild:object1];

SKSpriteNode *object2 = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithColor:[SKColor redColor] size:CGSizeMake(50, 50)];
object2.anchorPoint = CGPointMake(object1.anchorPoint.x, object1.anchorPoint.y);
object2.position = CGPointMake(0, 0);
[object1 addChild:object2];
```

Guaranteed to work or your money back! :)